# Can't use or set localleader in neovim

Tags: lua, neovim

I'm pretty new to neovim and vim in general and I tried to use the localleader key (default: \) and nothing happened.

Then I tried to set the localleader key in the config (lua) in various ways I could find online, none of which worked.

However when I type `:echo maplocalleader` in neovim it shows the key I set.

Setting maplocalleader from within neovim also yielded the same result.

My question is, what might be preventing my localleader key from working?

Comment: Hi! I recommend you strip your `init.lua` down to the smallest possible sample that replicates the problem you're having, and post it in your question. This also often has the happy effect of helping you fix the problem ;)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting up neovim again from scratch and copying over my configs piece by piece, I found out that I had to put `vim.g.maplocalleader = ";"` at the very top of init.lua in order for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to unmap the key first.
Try something like this.

```lua
local opts = { noremap = true, silent = true }
local keymap = vim.api.nvim_set_keymap

--Remap '\\' as leader key
keymap('', '\\', '<Nop>', opts)
vim.g.mapleader = '\\'
vim.g.maplocalleader = '\\'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to use `<leader><localleader>` whenever I need the `<localleader>`.

I am using NVChad distro, and using it with Neorg in `.norg` file. I don't know if it is my setting specific or what.